# typo3 solr how set default sorting?

Tags: solr, typo3

I use typo3 with solr search and i want to know how to set default sorting when no filter is selected ?
i have tried :

```
sorting.defaultOrder = asc
```

it give me empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug, see [Bug #61147](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/61147). There's also a workaround on this page.